# Basic C# Console Application Error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console-application

I've started learning C# today, I think I'm understanding it okay but I have 2 errors that I don't know how to fix. Could somebody explain the fix and why the problem occurred? I get the following errors: "} expected Line 30 after ReadLine" and "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected."

[image]

I tried entering it as code in here but it picked up the quote marks in my code and stopped half of the code goint into a code block.

Thanks everyone

Comment: try removing your `static void` methods out of `Main`. Place below

Comment: You can't have methods inside other methods (ignoring delegates I guess).

Comment: how are people supposed to copy/paste code from an image?

Comment: Move `PrintHelloToScreen` and `PrintHello100` out of `Main`

Comment: Post the code here, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Post the actual code please.

Comment: Read the error description! `}` expected!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a **}** after `Console.Readline();`

```
Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Your methods are within the closing } bracket of your main function. Move the methods so they are after the }

I didn't notice before. Miscounted the number of } brackets. :)

Comment: Thankyou everyone for the answers :) I have fixed the code, although I don't understand what you mean by cannot have a method inside a method :/

Comment: @VenomzHD You have your two methods `PrintHelloToScreen` and `PrintHello100` defined **inside** your main method. This is not valid code. By moving the closing brace as Shockwave indicated, you end your main method at that point which moves your two functions which are defined after that **outside** of the main method. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Precisely that. You cannot have a method inside a method. Your "static void Main" is a method, and it contains "static void PrintHelloToScreen" and "static void PrintHello100" which are both methods. It is a syntax error to have methods inside methods. The idea is to keep methods standalone so you can call them whenever you need to.